# copy a uploaded file in a git branch to the box where runner is executed using pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have created a branch in my gitlab and manually uploaded files into this branch (using upload option). Now, how can I copy this files into the box where the runner is executed using the pipeline yml file.

e.g.

```
stages:
- test
test_build:
stage:
 - test
script:
 - cp xxxx.jar ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
tags:
 - windows
```

Comment: Is the file committed to the same branch that your build is running for? If yes, it should be automatically present within the job's container, because the Runner [automatically checks out](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#ref-specs-for-runners) your repository to that branch.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Gitlab API for this https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/files/:file_path
```

Change your script from

```
- cp xxxx.jar ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
```

To

```
- |
  curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://$CI_SERVER_HOST/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/repository/files/xxxx.jar/raw?ref=<branch_name>" -o ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/xxxx.jar
```

If the **xxxx.jar** is in a folder
change the uri `files/xxxx.jar` to `files/folder%2Fnested_folder%2Fxxxx.jar`